# Mapped Network Drives not available in Citrix application depending on local machine

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine, group-policy, network-drive, citrix

It's simpler than the title suggests.

When I log into a remote application via Citrix XenApp from Box A (Windows XP) and Box B (Windows 7) I can see all local physical disks and locally mapped network drives, in addition to the drives mapped within the remote application itself.

However, when I log into that same application from Box C (a virtual Windows 7 environment) I can't see any local drives at all, whether "physical" or mapped.

Because the drives can be seen from Box A and B I know that the remote environment is mapping the drives OK (i.e. XenApp is set up correctly) but Box C is obviously hiding these drives from the remote application.

How is that being done and is there anyway I can confirm it what restrictions are in place using just regedit.  I don't have access to admin tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally discovered this was due to a system policy implemented at the administrator level. I would have needed admin tools to discover this for myself.

Answer (score 0):

Have you opened the connection center on the virtual 7 box to check the file access restrictions? For each server you connect to via Citrix, there's a drop-down box that gives permission to the server to access local drives. I believe it's located on the right hand side.

Comment: I didn't even think of that but I have tried it and it doesn't help. I think it's a group policy on the W7 box.